# how to enable vertical scroling of web view layout with in scrollview tag

Tags: android

I have problem in scrolling of webview vertically when it's scrolled along vertically,where this webview is with in scrollview tag,how can i enable the scrolling for webview and to disable the scrolling of whole layout when its on webview contained layout.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way touch events are consume in android it is not recommended or even really possible to have two Views that consume and react to the same move events in the same axis. In other words, you cannot put a `WebView` in a `ScrollView`. You would not be able to put a `ListView` in a `ScrollView` and have it work either since they both scroll vertically.